# How do I calculate solution of this recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

*How do I calculate solution of this recurrence relation preferably by an easy way?*

$$T (m, n) = T (m-1, n-1) + T (m, n-1) + T (m-1, n) + C $$

I came across [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) link but couldn't connect the dots....

Any **help** would be preferred or a hint or a useful link will also do....

*assuming that T(m, n) at all initial conditions is zero*

Comment: What do you mean by complexity?

Comment: Solution to this recurrence

Comment: What are the initial values of $T(m,n)$?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [A047662](http://oeis.org/A047662) but there is a connection to [A008288](http://oeis.org/A008288) which has a formula.